# CakePHP 2.x - Hash::filter - How to set a callback function? // PHP Filter

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, filter

I want to filter an array over Hash::filter and use a callback function

> static Hash::filter(array $data, $callback = array('Hash', 'filter'))
>
> ...You can also supply a custom $callback to filter the array elements...
> (CakePHP Docs)

My question here is just... How?

Maybe there's a failure in my head with the translations, but i have the JavaScript filter function in mind, where you can filter over an array and give the filterfunction the actual element its iterating over atm. Then if it returns false it gets kicked out of the array.

maybe im just bad with php but.. could anybody help me with it, please? :)

my attempt atm is something like this

```
$bis_datum = '2017-01-01';
$res = Hash::filter($multidim_assoc_array, function($part_of_multidim_assoc_array){
        return !strtotime($assoc_array['von_datum']) > strtotime($bis_datum);
});
```

i know there's something very wrong here, because it sais

> array('Hash', 'filter')

in the docs and theres just an anonymous function here, but i dont get what the "Hash" and "filter" part means :S

```
$example = array(

'User' => array(
    0 => array(
        'name' => 'Bob',
        'age' => 25
    ),
    1 => array(
        'name' => 'John',
        'age' => 22
    ),
    2 => array(
        'name' => 'Jen',
        'age' => 32
    )
)

'School' => array(
    'name' => 'Brainslaves High',
    'adress' => 'Somestreet 42'
)
);
```

as an easy example.. how can i filter this array to kick out everyone whos age is below 25 ?

Thanks-a-lot!

Comment: actualy, the definition of the function is `static Hash::filter(array $data, $callback = array('Hash', '_filter'))` and not `static Hash::filter(array $data, $callback = array('Hash', 'filter'))` . Did you notice the underscore ?

Comment: Wow thanks for that fast reply! gonna test it out :)

but whats the difference between _filter and filter? (sorry if its a stupid question :S)

Comment: they are two different methods of Hash class. @see https://api.cakephp.org/2.9/source-class-Hash.html#558 and https://api.cakephp.org/2.9/source-class-Hash.html#573

Comment: oh well, idiot me.. once again thanks a lot :) guess i'm not fully into reading the docs correctly, yet!

if i'm home i'll test out your answer and give it a sign :)

Comment: oh - one last question

whats the 'self' in $callback = array('self', '_filter') for? specific declaration for something? if yes - is there kind of a list for the key words?

Comment: ok buddy, that's basic PHP :D

Comment: self referes to the class itself, used to call static methods and properties .... @see http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: this happens when you start working with php with a framework :S 

thanks again! ill give it a look and give my brain some input :) 

over and out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Hash::filter` won't help you for your example, you better work with `array_filter`directly

```
$res = array('User' => array_filter($example['User'], function($user) {
                    return $user['age'] > 25;
                })) + array('School' => $example['School']);
```